# Can't connect to SQL Server 2014 databases using Tomcat 7 under linux

Tags: java, sql-server, linux, tomcat

It's a couple of days we are wondering what is the reason for this particular database connection problem with our Spring web application.

Stack:

- Linux Centos 8.1
- Tomcat 7.0.96
- SQL Server 2014
- Microsoft JDBC Driver For SQL Server 6.1.0.jre8
- Spring 4.1.6.RELEASE
- Hibernate 4.3.5.Final
- c3p0-0.9.2.1.jar
- Java 8

What we see is that we havo no problems connecting to Sql Server instances like Sql Server 2016 and 2019, **but absolutely can't gain connection to Sql Server 2014 instances**.

I tried to simply update the JDBC drivers to the 8.2.1.jre8 version, but nothing changed.

**The same codebase under Windows (Windows 10 in my local test case) works without problems also with 2014 instances.**

Here are the db connection info from out xml configuration file:

```
<bean id="testRoutingDataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource">
    <property name="driverClass" value="com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver" />
    <property name="jdbcUrl"
        value="jdbc:sqlserver://ip_address;databaseName=db_name" />
    <property name="user" value="redacted" />
    <property name="password" value="redacted" />
    <property name="maxIdleTime" value="600" />
    <property name="maxPoolSize" value="200" />
    <property name="maxStatements" value="200" />
    <property name="minPoolSize" value="15" />
    <property name="idleConnectionTestPeriod" value="100" />
    <property name="acquireIncrement" value="3" />
    <property name="numHelperThreads" value="20" />
    <property name="connectionCustomizerClassName"
        value="it.sabacom.interceptors.IsolationLevelConnectionCustomizer" />
</bean>
```

In the `hibernate.cfg.xml` file the dialect used is an extension of  `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect`

Here's the stacktrace of the error at the startup of the server:

```
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
```

and

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:689)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:164)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
... 125 more
```

Full stacktrace:

```
 
org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:125)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:143)
    at it.sabacom.multiTenant.TenantDaoProviderAuthentication.authenticate(TenantDaoProviderAuthentication.java:52)
    at it.sabacom.multiTenant.TenantDaoProviderAuthentication$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$229f63c9.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at it.sabacom.logging.TimingProfilerProduction.logTimeMethod(TimingProfilerProduction.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor294.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at it.sabacom.multiTenant.TenantDaoProviderAuthentication$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$39ee9bcf.authenticate()
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:167)
    at org.springframework.flex.security3.SpringSecurityLoginCommand.doAuthentication(SpringSecurityLoginCommand.java:115)
    at flex.messaging.security.LoginManager.login(LoginManager.java:221)
    at flex.messaging.services.AuthenticationService.decodeAndLoginWithCharset(AuthenticationService.java:223)
    at flex.messaging.services.AuthenticationService.serviceCommand(AuthenticationService.java:142)
    at flex.messaging.MessageBroker.routeCommandToService(MessageBroker.java:1503)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint.serviceMessage(AbstractEndpoint.java:982)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.AbstractEndpoint$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$1a3ef066.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.flex.core.MessageInterceptionAdvice.invoke(MessageInterceptionAdvice.java:66)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.invoke(ThrowsAdviceInterceptor.java:125)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$FixedChainStaticTargetInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:603)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30c89c5a.serviceMessage()
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.MessageBrokerFilter.invoke(MessageBrokerFilter.java:103)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.LegacyFilter.invoke(LegacyFilter.java:158)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SessionFilter.invoke(SessionFilter.java:44)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.BatchProcessFilter.invoke(BatchProcessFilter.java:67)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.amf.SerializationFilter.invoke(SerializationFilter.java:166)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.BaseHTTPEndpoint.service(BaseHTTPEndpoint.java:291)
    at flex.messaging.endpoints.SecureAMFEndpoint$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$30c89c5a.service()
    at org.springframework.flex.servlet.MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.handle(MessageBrokerHandlerAdapter.java:109)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:959)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:893)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:966)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:868)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:842)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at it.sabacom.logging.MDCInsertingServletFilter.doFilter(MDCInsertingServletFilter.java:81)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:316)
    at it.sabanet.core.security.filter.NodoLoggatoFilter.doFilter(NodoLoggatoFilter.java:52)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:126)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:90)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:114)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:122)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:111)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:48)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:64)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:53)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:213)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:176)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.web.Log4jServletFilter.doFilter(Log4jServletFilter.java:71)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:110)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:444)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:104)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:1025)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:445)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1137)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:637)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1780)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1739)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException: Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:544)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:373)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.createTransactionIfNecessary(TransactionAspectSupport.java:463)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:276)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at it.sabacom.dao.profilazione.UtenteDAO$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5456d32b.loadUserByUsername()
    at it.sabacom.service.profilazione.DefaultUtenteService.loadUserByUsername(DefaultUtenteService.java:21)
    at it.sabacom.service.profilazione.DefaultUtenteService$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$b2f0e4e1.invoke()
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:204)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:717)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85)
    at it.sabacom.logging.TimingProfilerProduction.logTimeMethod(TimingProfilerProduction.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor294.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:621)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:610)
    at org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:68)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:653)
    at it.sabacom.service.profilazione.DefaultUtenteService$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$d10ed1e7.loadUserByUsername()
    at it.sabanet.core.security.service.MasterUserDetailService.loadUserByUsername(MasterUserDetailService.java:44)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:114)
    ... 113 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open connection
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:54)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:126)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:112)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:235)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.getConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:171)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.connection(SessionImpl.java:450)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager.doBegin(HibernateTransactionManager.java:450)
    ... 142 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
    at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:118)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:689)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:140)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.lookup.AbstractRoutingDataSource.getConnection(AbstractRoutingDataSource.java:164)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.getConnection(DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSessionImpl$NonContextualJdbcConnectionAccess.obtainConnection(AbstractSessionImpl.java:380)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.LogicalConnectionImpl.obtainConnection(LogicalConnectionImpl.java:228)
    ... 145 more
Caused by: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.CannotAcquireResourceException: A ResourcePool could not acquire a resource from its primary factory or source.
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.awaitAvailable(BasicResourcePool.java:1418)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.prelimCheckoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:606)
    at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.checkoutResource(BasicResourcePool.java:526)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutAndMarkConnectionInUse(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:755)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:682)
    ... 150 more
```

**ADDED INFO AFTER ANISH.B ANSWER**

- I tried upgrading the sql server dialect using `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect` but nothing changed
- This is my pom.xml reference to the (upgraded) mssql jdbc driver:

  ```
  <dependency>
      <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
      <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
      <version>8.2.1.jre8</version>
  </dependency>
  ```
- I don't think it's a problem of corrupted jars, since the same war that i pack it's working with a Tomcat under Windows and not working witha Tomcat under Linux

** EDIT - I replaced the previous stacktrace with a new one**
Added pastebin for clarity: https://pastebin.com/8rDhZjLn

Comment: what is going on here verificaEsistenzaParametriReuperoPassword? Are you using correct credentials? And please add config for how you connect to the database

Comment: yes the credentials are all correct. I tried it using the same connection info with the same codebase changing only the underlying OS (Windows instead of CentOS).
I'm adding the connection configuration in the post, thanks.

Comment: To me it looks like your jdbcUrl is lacking port, like :1433. But I am no expert. Have a look here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/using-the-jdbc-driver?view=sql-server-ver15 The sql server instance must also expose TCP Port 1433

Comment: port 1433 is the default, no need to specify (we do if the port is different). Shouldn't be a problem on sql server side, because if the tomcat is under windows the connection works without problems even with 2014 instances.
Thanks anyway

Comment: Will you go for c3p0-hibernate integration configuration ? It will be easier for you

Comment: The stacktrace suggests that your pool is exhausted (no available connections). Are you sure your code is correctly closing connections when it is done (that is what returns them to the connection pool).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I don't think it's a pool issue, but you gave me the idea of monitoring it via JMX. I don't think it's that the problem since out configuration (not the simple one I posted here for clarity) is multitenant, and we don't have any problems connecting to tenants backed by SqlServer 2016/2019. If we had a connections leak problem taht should be indipendent of sql server

Comment: In that case, are you sure the stacktrace isn't deeper? Because if the pool itself isn't exhausted, it means there is a problem obtaining connections, and then I would expect an underlying cause from the SQL Server driver contained in that `CannotAcquireResourceException`.

Comment: ok @MarkRotteveel, I'm adding the entire stacktrace of another test I completed now.

Comment: this is a pastebin to the stacktrace: https://pastebin.com/8rDhZjLn